# How to use my own domain in Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Have explored on how to do this but still cant make it work :(
I want to point my subdomain myapp.example.com to GAE

What I have done:
- Deploy my application to Google App Engine
- sign up Google Apps with name myapp.example.com
- add cname myapp.example.com with value ghs.google.com
- wait for dns changes..

but until now when I access myapp.example.com google return error message "Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server."
ping result of myapp.example.com is ghs.l.google.com

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to add your App Engine app to the Google Apps domain through your App Engine Dashboard. See step 3 here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

Comment: Yes I have done that too.. 
after I click add domain it redirect me to google apps.. after that I lost.. I even can't verify my domain myapp.example.com

Comment: @user701598 You need to verify that you are the owner of "example.com". I guess you didnt do that: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=60216

Answer (score 0):

The way I do likewise for my projects is mapping the GAE application to a subdomain in the google apps control panel (google.com/a) An example is video.montao.com.br that is a google app engine app. I think that you may have left out adding the application in the google apps control panel.